# Accessing <link>, <script>, < img> and <a> from anywhere

Tags: php, html

I have header, menu and footer include files that maybe accessed from anywhere in a folder structure. To date everything that those file load I have given a full url simply because I can’t find any other reliable way to load them from anywhere in the folder structure. Whilst this works, it is far from ideal and totally useless when it comes to developing with XAMPP.

```
<?php include(__DIR__ . '/inc_menu.php');?>
```

This works perfectly when ‘including’ or ‘requiring’, can someone please explain how to make something similar work with `<link>`, `<script>`, `< img>` and `<a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use URLs relative to the root directory for the site. i.e. URLs that begin with a `/` character.

Comment: I will add that once you start working with root relative paths in an environment where your header / footer files can be included from anywhere within the application structure, you will not regret it.

Comment: @Dale Wow! The simplest things are often the most effective. Many thanks for filling an obvious void in my knowledge.